# dotnet Cli error trying to generate code coverage stats

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core, command-line-interface, cobertura

I'm running the following command to run my .net Core tests:

```
dotnet test
```

This runs fine.  I want to now generate code coverage stats, so after following this article, I ran this:

```
dotnet test AI.Core.Tests.csproj 
  /p:CollectCoverage=true 
  /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
  /p:CoverletOutput=TestResults\Coverage
```

I get the following output from this command:

```
C:\Users\sp4_rm\.nuget\packages\coverlet.msbuild\2.2.1\build\netstandard2.0\coverlet.msbuild.targets(23,5): error : 
  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
  [C:\Users\sp4_rm\Desktop\EVO\AI.Core\src\Tests\AI.Core.Tests.csproj]

 C:\Users\sp4_rm\.nuget\packages\coverlet.msbuild\2.2.1\build\netstandard2.0\coverlet.msbuild.targets(23,5): error : 
  Parameter name: index 
  [C:\Users\sp4_rm\Desktop\EVO\AI.Core\src\Tests\AI.Core.Tests.csproj]
```

See screen shot below:

[image]

Has anyone got this command running?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't share what article you were following. Maybe it was this one http://tattoocoder.com/cross-platform-code-coverage-arrives-for-net-core/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this was due to a school boy error in not actually have any code to test (or test case to test it) in my sample project!!  Adding a couple of classes into the main projects and a couple of tests in the test project does away with this problem!  (just in case anyway does the same thing as me!)

Comment: I had the exact same issue - obvious now I think about it!